# How to install XAMPP in new windows without losing data

Tags: php, apache, xampp, windows-10, htdocs

I have re-installed Windows 10 and I had installed XAMPP on Drive D of my computer.

Now the folder `XAMPP` still exists there but I try to open it and clicked on `START` Apache, I get this error:

`The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).`

However the MySQL starts properly.

So the question is, should I re-install the XAMPP again to run it properly or there is some other way to start it on this new Windows?

If I have to install it, should I just install it on another drive and copy and paste `htdocs` & `mysql` in order to load the files properly or I can overwrite them by using the path of old xampp in Drive D?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or solution about this...

Actually I'm a little a bit worried about losing my files, so please help me how to handle it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can install 2 xampp in one device.

I ever install xampp php 5 and xampp php 7, just different by name.

But, for safer you can backup before